# How to check if a string only contains 1 character using swift

Tags: string, swift, if-statement, character

How can I check if a string only contains 1 character using an if statement in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy, use this:

```
var str:String = "a"

if str.characters.count == 1 {

}
```